# Angular REST data not displaying in view correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Heres the Angular app:

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $q) {

```
$q.all([
$http.get('http://private-bc4b97-commutertransport.apiary-mock.com/bus'),
$http.get('http://private-bc4b97-commutertransport.apiary-mock.com/otm')
 ]).then(function(results) {
 $scope.network = results[0].data;
 $scope.data = results[1].data

})

});
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<h1>{{network.test1}}</h1>
<h1>{{data.test2}}</h1>
</div>
```

And the basic JSON (in different URL to each other of course):

```
"test1" : "first test",
"test2" : "second test",
```

Now the console is showing the HTTP being called successfully but the data isn't being displayed in view... Not really sure whats wrong?

Console log screen:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the network request in your browser with the JSON payload returned from the API?

Comment: Use debugger to see what the returned result type is. If headers are not correct JSON is not parsed automatically, so you have a string. In this case the expression in view can't find any nested `.test1` or `.test2` because `data` and `network` are strings

Comment: !. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info 2. Learn to debug. 3. Profit

Comment: screenie added of the console

Comment: Are you sure `results` is an array? Have you tried with only `results.data`?

Comment: results is most definitely an array since he is using $q.all() and passing in two promises

Comment: Its fixed now guys, thanks for the help, went through the debugger seemed it was an issue with the JSON. All done!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging your response in the console; in my experience with Angular's $http service (when using the .then method), response data is wrapped in a response object and is returned in the data property of that object:

```
$scope.network = results[0].data;
$scope.data = results[1].data;
```

Comment: so what would I be console logging, 'results'?

Comment: Just do like console.log('results', results[0], results[1]) and what you should see is an object that has a data property.

Comment: managed to fix it, error with the JSON :P anyway thanks for the help bro, I know you helped me yesterday so thanks again

Comment: was going through that angular app again today and part of your syntax got me thinking so I thought I may as well ask, when you're calling $scope.network = results[0].data I was thinking of calling an array so I would put $scope.network = results[0].networkupdate instead (networkupdate being the name of the array), from my understanding. I Tried this method, to no success, so is this incorrect under a '.then' method?

Comment: No, everything that comes back in your response will be nested under data. So, if the 'networkupdate' property is an array that's returned in your response data, you would set `$scope.network = results[0].data.networkupdate`.